# On my IIS7 how to I enable the download size for Internet Explorer to give an estimate download time

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, internet-explorer-8

I have an IIS7 server, which people download exe files from.

When people are using Internet explorer the download dialog box says that the size is unknown.

What setting in IIS will allow the clients to know the size of the file?

Comment: Are the files being served up by an application (e.g. ASP.NET), or are they straight links to the actual exe files in question?

Answer (score 0):

IIS 7 has chunked encoding enabled by default - and according to RFC 2616 you cannot use the `Content-Length` header (which is used to let the client know how big the content being sent is) with chunked encoding.

I think you need to disable chunked encoding under ASP settings in IIS.